# how to page the result of select query based on its data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table defined as this: tbl01(data), data is varchar(max). The data is populated with variable number of fixed length of strings. For example (this is just example, not real data),

```
insert into tbl01 values(replicate(‘a’, 5)+char(13)+char(10)+ replicate(‘b’, 5))
insert into tbl01 values(replicate(‘b’, 5))
insert into tbl01 values(replicate(‘c’, 5)+char(13)+char(10)+space(5)+char(13)+char(10)+ replicate(‘d’, 5))
```

The table would look like:

```
aaaaabbbbb
bbbbb
ccccc     ddddd
```

when I export the table to a txt file there will be 6 lines.

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
bbbbb
ccccc

ddddd
```

Now I need paging the data like two lines per page, and add page header and footer, for example

```
Page 1 header
aaaaa
bbbbb
Page 1 footer
Page 2 header
bbbbb
ccccc
Page 2 footer
Page 3 header

ddddd
Page 3 footer
```

The show stopper is how to page the this table, since the number of lines for each row are variable?

Comment: Paging in a txt file? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Yeh I need add page header and footer in the text file. But I need page the query result first right?

Comment: I think I can guess...but can you show us the desired query output?

Comment: I updated my question, hopefully it is clear enough

Comment: Are you getting data from a stored procedure? Are you repetitively requesting data or is it coming back in one request with the above formatting?

Comment: I have to add the page header and footer in stored procedure.

Comment: May we assume `tbl01` has a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (tested in SQL 2012).  I assumed a PK with incrementing values.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tbl01 (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    SomeData VARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

insert into #Tbl01 values(replicate('a', 5)+char(13)+char(10)+ replicate('b', 5))
insert into #Tbl01 values(replicate('b', 5))
insert into #Tbl01 values(replicate('c', 5)+char(13)+char(10)+space(5)+char(13)+char(10)+ replicate('d', 5))
GO

--This CTE displays the original rows that were inserted, plus the "lines" in each row broken out into separate rows.
;WITH RawData AS
(
    SELECT ID AS RowId, SomeData, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), SomeData, 1) NewLinePos, 1 StringNumber
    FROM #Tbl01
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RowId, RIGHT(SomeData, DATALENGTH(SomeData) - NewLinePos - 1), 
        CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), RIGHT(SomeData, DATALENGTH(SomeData) - NewLinePos - 1), 1), StringNumber + 1
    FROM RawData
    WHERE NewLinePos > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RowId, LEFT(SomeData, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), SomeData, 1)), 0, StringNumber
    FROM RawData
    WHERE NewLinePos > 0
),

--This CTE shows just the "lines" broken out into separate rows with grouping info.
DataLines AS
(
    SELECT SomeData,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowId, StringNumber) RowNum, 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowId, StringNumber) + 1) / 2 GroupNum, 2 GroupItemOrder
    FROM RawData
    WHERE NewLinePos = 0
),

--This CTE creates the output rows for paging.
OutputLines AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM DataLines
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN RowNum % 2 = 1 THEN 'Page ' + CAST(GroupNum AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' header'
            ELSE 'Page ' + CAST(GroupNum AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' footer'
        END,
        RowNum, GroupNum,
        CASE 
            WHEN RowNum % 2 = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 3
        END

    FROM OutputLines 
    WHERE GroupItemOrder = 2
)
--Final query is the output rows for paging in the correct order.
SELECT SomeData
FROM OutputLines
ORDER BY GroupNum, GroupItemOrder

--Cleanup as needed
--DROP TABLE #Tbl01
```